# Can we have adjectives before objective personal pronouns, for example, "I have some photos of baby him"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

THis is a part of the script in the social network film

> Erica Albright : Well, why don't you just concentrate on being the
> best you you can be.
>
> Mark Zuckerberg : Did you really just say that?
>
> Erica Albright : I was kidding. Although just because something's
> trite doesn't make it any less true.

They say "**the best you**", so I reckon we can have some adjectives before objective personal pronouns.

Can we have adjectives before objective personal pronouns, for example, "**I have some photos of baby him**"?

Comment: In my photo album are pictures of: baby him, two-year-old me, elderly Dad. Lucky me!

Answer (score 0):

> *Well, why don't you just concentrate on being* [*the best you (that) you can be*].

"(That) you can be" is a relative clause modifying "you", where "that" is optional.

Thus, "the best you (that) you can be" is a noun phrase in which "you" is modified by the relative clause "(that) you can be".

In your other example "I have some photos of baby him", "baby him" is a noun phrase in which the objective pronoun "him" is modified by the nominal "baby".

Comment: No, @BillJ, the quote in the OP is “the best you you can be,” which means, essentially, “the best version of yourself.” It has something of the flavor of “You 2.0.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Yes, of course. I hastily misread the two you's as being a typo. I have corrected my answer. Interestingly, the first "you" is head of the whole NP, while the second is complement of "be" in the relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ I agree about the relative clause, but OP's question is still valid since in the phrase "the **best** you ([that] you can be)," "**best**" is an adjective modifying the pronoun "you." It's not an *objective* personal pronoun though, since "to be" is followed by a predicate, not an object.

Comment: It goes without saying that "best" modifies"you". Unlike most of the other personal pronouns, there is no case distinction with "you". We generally refer to it as 'plain' case.